# Posting Razor textarea back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a ViewModel that wraps two lists of different objects: `List<Review> Reviews` and `DayCommentary DayCommentary` into `ReviewViewModel`. In my view, I group `Reviews` by `Review.Country`:

```
var groupedReviews = Model.Reviews.GroupBy(item => item.Country)
```

In the view, I loop through `groupedReviews` and build an HTML table for each `group`. My goal is to output each `Review` in `group` while still binding to the model for posting back to the controller. This is important because in the view I have a textarea field that needs to be pass entered text back to the controller during POST actions. I understand that this requires a for-loop rather than a foreach to maintain the binding.

I've thus tried the following, which displays correctly in the view but does not bind to the model during `FormMethod.Post`, for example during a Add/Edit/Delete controller action:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Review", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (var group in groupedReviews)
    {
        <h6>@Html.Raw(group.Key)</h6>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reviews[0].Ticker)
                </th>
            </tr>
            @for (var i = 0; i < group.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => group.ElementAt(i).Commentary)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => group.ElementAt(i).Commentary)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem here is with `ElementAt(i)`, but what can I use instead when iterating through this type of grouped collection?

I've tried assigning `name` and `id` attributes to the TextArea field as suggested in answers to some similar questions to no avail.

I've been going in circles trying to use different types of loops and iterating over different collections but nothing achieves my desired goal.

Comment: model => group[i].Commentary?

Comment: Tried this and get this error: "Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string,Review>'" because my grouping key is of type `string`, not `int` whereas I'm iterating over the `.Count()` of group.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the key. And you not iterating over `.Count()` - your iterating over a collection. Make the collection `List<Review >` (by using `.ToList()`) so that you can use indexing.

Comment: I've done this @StephenMuecke and although this displays fine in the view, when posting the form back to the controller, my Review object is null.

Comment: You have not included a control for the key. But you really need to create a view model for this - `class ReviewGroupVM` containing properties `string GroupName` and `List<Review>`, and in the view use nested `for` loops so you get 2 way strongly typed binding

Comment: I currently have a view model, `ReviewViewModel` that contains properties `List<Review> Reviews` and `DayCommentary DayCommentary`. Are you saying I'll need to create a new view model (e.g., `ReviewGroupViewModel`) and change my existing controller-bound view model (`ReviewViewModel`) to have properties `List<ReviewGroupViewModel> ReviewGroups` and `DayCommentary DayCommentary`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've also tried the alternative of adding a `@HiddenFor(model => group.Key`. Is this what you meant by including a control for the key, I'm not really sure what a control is in the ASP.NET MVC context... Is the HiddenFor helper inappropriate for this?

Comment: Create a view model to represent what your editing as I noted in my previous comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91036/discussion-between-illya-and-stephen-muecke).